# Standard fields translation

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

I need to translate product names and their descriptions, using workbench i can only translate cutoms fields.
Is there a reliable ISV or API that i can use for translation?
thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the 'Rename Tabs and Labels' options in the setup if you wish to change the labels of standard fields

Comment: So this will actually be the data within the Org that you need translated as the Product Name and Description are data. There is no native support for this in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Product Name and Description are data rather than configuration Salesforce has no native tools to do this.

You can either create a record for each language you need to support for each product with the name and description in the correct language and then have a custom language picklist field on the Product object to help filter the records displayed to the user based on their language settings. The issue with this is for reporting on sales of a product multiple records represent the same product depending on language.

The only other native alternative is to have additional custom fields with translations and a language picklist to select which field is displayed to the user based on language. This will only work for a very small set of languages.

There do not seem to be many ISV tools for Sales as most are focused on Service with Case and Knowledge Article translation.

These tools are on the AppExchange but I do not have direct experience of them to  comment on how effective they are. I have no commercial or other relationship to these vendors.

[S4G Omnitranslate](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJuLQUA1)

[SDL Instant translation](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A000000rMnUUAU)

Answer (score -1):

To change the Standard field name

**Salesforce Classic**

1. Setup | Customize | Tab Names and Labels | Rename Tabs and Labels
2. Select the object of your choice.
3. Edit the page (you can edit the object name).
4. Click Next. On this second edit page you can edit the record name as well as the other Standard fields.
5. Click Save.

**Lightning Experience**

1. Gear icon | Setup | User Interface | Rename Tabs and Labels
2. Select the object of your choice.
3. Edit page, you can edit the object name.
4. Click Next. On this second edit page you can edit the record name as well as the other Standard fields.
5. Click Save.

Note:

If using the Translation Workbench,  only apply the changes for Custom Object or Custom fields and not Standard Objects or Standard Fields.

Languages can be set on the user record. Users also can edit this themselves in My Personal Information.

See this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315332&type=1&mode=1) to learn more